# How to detect that User has added webapp to the homescreen on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am working on a webapp. I want to count the number of Users that added my webapp to home screen.

suppose my website is.

http://www.example.com

I have added meta tags that allow Mobile users to add it to home screen. I want a count of users that downloaded my webapp. If User has downloaded even if he has not opened that then also I should get notification that User has added it to home screen.

So I need any event that should work when an Webapp is added to home screen.

My webapp is in HTML5

Answer (score 2):

First of all, officially it's not possible, as per the official FAQ:

> **How can I detect if the app is running as an installed app?**
>
> You can’t, directly.

which is again re-iterated

> ### Best practices
>
> - Do not prompt the user to add your app to the homescreen. There is no way to detect if the app is running installed or not.

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen

You could do some manual checking of the screen sizes though on page load, as chrome can't go fullscreen by hand, but do not rely on this (though for statistical purposes it might be interesting).

---

Another clarification which might be useful, the application is not downloaded when it's added to the homescreen. All that happens is that a 'link' will be created to chrome with certain parameters. By design little information is disclosed to developers regarding this process to prevent companies from forcing users to 'install' webapps before they would function.

Comment: I can check using window.navigator.standalone after opening the webapp. But I need to check if he has installed or not event if he has not opened the app.. as per you we can't do it...

Comment: @user1081463: I am pretty sure that that's an iOS property, not an android one. But let me check in a sec.

Comment: @user1081463: Ah, yeah, already got worried I was 'walking behind the facts' as we Dutch would say :P . Either way, there indeed is no way to get an event when the user installs the application (and resolution checking is quite unreliable on android after the fact either way).

Answer (score 1):

As of 2018, according to https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/:

> To determine if the app was successfully added to the user's home screen after they accepted the prompt, you can listen for the appinstalled event.
>
> ```
> window.addEventListener('appinstalled', (evt) => {
>   app.logEvent('a2hs', 'installed');
> });
> ```